# How to protect encrypted key file in K8S Encrypt at rest?

Tags: kubernetes

With api-server argument:

```
--encryption-provider-config=/etc/kubernetes/config/encryption.yaml
```

Because even though ETCD is encrypted, but the secret file to decrypt remains on the master node.

Comment: Did my answer solve your doubts?

Comment: I would like to discuss about even you encrypt data before write etcd but how it more safe because key to decrypt has been store in master node. @Alez

Comment: Your etcd command contains the path to the key used to encrtypt the data. So etcd takes that key and use it to encrypt and decrypt the contents. Thus, you should properly restrict the access to control plane to keep the key safe.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [Kubernetes 1.7](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/06/kubernetes-1-7-security-hardening-stateful-application-extensibility-updates/), Kubernetes added some additional features regarding to security like encrypting components in etcd.

This allows sensitive data stored in the etcd database to be encrypted, allowing users to protect it from being read by third-parties with the Kubernetes API. This is a further feature to the disk-level encryption that protects data only if they are inside the disk.

Answer (score 0):

[Encryption at rest](https://cloud.google.com/docs/security/encryption/default-encryption#how_encryption_at_rest_helps_to_secure_data) is one piece of a broader security strategy.

> Encryption has the following benefits:
>
> Helps to ensure that if data falls into an attacker's hands, the
> attacker cannot read the data without also having access to the
> encryption keys. Even if attackers obtain the storage devices that
> contain customer data, they won't be able to understand or decrypt it.
>
> Helps to reduce the surface of attack by cutting out the lower layers
> of the hardware and software stack. Acts as a chokepoint because
> centrally managed encryption keys create a single place where access
> to data is enforced and can be audited.
>
> Helps to reduce the attack surface because instead of having to
> protect all data, businesses can focus their protection strategies on
> the encryption keys.
>
> Provides an important privacy mechanism for our customers. When data
> is encrypted at rest, it limits the access that systems and engineers
> have to the data